# Selenium find all <em> and the following <a> tags

Tags: selenium

I want to get all em and the following a tags, but these are seperated:

```
<em style="color: #FF2500;">ITEM:</em> <a href="LINK"> LINK </a><br />
<em style="color: #FF2500;">ITEM2:</em> <a href="LINK2"> LINK2 </a><br />
<em style="color: #FF2500;">ITEM3:</em> <a href="LINK3">LINK3 </a><br />
```

I need to save the ITEM and the correspinding LINK, because they must be together, but I only managed to find the text of the links:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//em/following-sibling::a[@href]")
```

printing this gives me only the contents of the link:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//em/following-sibling::a[@href]")
for link in elems:
    print (link.text) # LINK, LINK2, LINK3
```

I could of course find all em and links by themself, but I wouldnt know if they fit together. So I need  to find:

All `<em>` where an `<a>` with a certain text follows. This way I should know for sure that they are together.

Answer (score 1):

Searches `em` preceding to `a` with some `text`

```
 //a[text()=' LINK2 '] | //a[text()=' LINK2 ']/preceding-sibling::em[1]
```

to get just text concatenated from both elements

```
concat(//a[text()=' LINK2 ']/preceding-sibling::em[1], //a[text()=' LINK2 '])
```

result:

```
"ITEM2: LINK2 "
```

Comment: I need both, the content of the em tag + the content of the a tag

Comment: updated) just add same locator and OR operator as in my answer)